# Can someone fix the following Data.Binary example code?

Tags: haskell

Trying to learn how to use Data.Binary and hit a roadblock here:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Serialisation_and_compression_with_Data_Binary

```
D:\Projects\haskell\serialize\ex1.hs:114:26:
    Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.9.1.10:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                with actual type `L.ByteString'
    Expected type: Int
                   -> bytestring-0.9.1.10:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
      Actual type: Int -> L.ByteString
    In the return type of a call of `toByteString'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `toByteString f'

D:\Projects\haskell\serialize\ex1.hs:122:21:
    Couldn't match expected type `L.ByteString'
                with actual type `bytestring-0.9.1.10:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
    In the first argument of `L.length', namely `fs'
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `L.length fs'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `L.length fs + L.length is'
[Finished]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your Cabal packages are in a mess; you have multiple versions of the `bytestring` package installed, and they're conflicting. The most likely scenario is that the `binary` package depends on a different version of `bytestring` to the one you get when you import `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.

The easiest thing to do is probably to start from scratch by clearing out your Cabal directories. On Windows, these directories seem to be `C:\Program Files\Haskell` and `C:\Documents And Settings\username\Application Data\cabal`. However, I think indiscriminately clearing the former would uninstall the Haskell Platform altogether, so be careful; on the other hand, the easiest thing might be to uninstall the Haskell Platform and start again. (Additionally, you'll probably want to copy out the `config` file first, to avoid overwriting your Cabal configuration.)

[`cabal-dev`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev) is useful to keep problems like this isolated; it builds each program in its own sandbox, so that the effects of package problems are localised and can be cleaned up easily. I don't know how well it works on Windows, though.

Comment: I deleted cabal and ghc from \user\AppData\Roaming\ and uninstalled haskell platform then deleted the leftover dir and reinstalled. Now I have cabal-dev installed and I used it to get the binary package, but now get the following error on the example code: `Could not find module 'Data.Binary':
      It is a member of the hidden package 'ghc-binary-0.5.0.2'`.

Comment: Forgot to add that cabal-dev installed binary to C:\Users\...\cabal-dev/binary-0.5.1.0\ghc-7.0.4

Comment: With cabal-dev, you have to write a Cabal file for your project listing all your dependencies. `cabal init` will walk you through generating a basic Cabal file, but it might be easiest to simply `cabal install binary` and try compiling the program again, rather than trying to get cabal-dev working. (You can remove that cabal-dev directory; it's meant to go where your project is, not in a system directory.)